# Create custom element similar to img tag

Tags: javascript, html, polymer, web-component

I want to create a custom img tag  that behaves exactly like

```
<my-img src="my-image.png" alt="" />
```

How can I do that?

Comment: So what's the problem? https://www.polymer-project.org/1.0/ contains lots of docs about how to create a component.

Comment: They all have an <img> tag inside the custom tag I don't want to have the <img> tag at all example: https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-image?view=demo:demo/index.html&active=iron-image

Comment: Then you'll have a hard time. The `<img>` tag is what displays images in HTML.

Comment: I have no problem with that the only thing I'm concerned is if it is possible to do it or not?

Comment: No, if you want to display an image within your element you need to use the `<img>` tag.

Comment: Ok thanks for the advice

Comment: You could use a canvas instead of img tag. load the image, read the pixel data, display it on the canvas.

Comment: Of course you can! You don't need polymer.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this?

```
<dom-module id="my-img">
    <template>
        <img src="[[src]]" />
    </template>     
    <script>
        Polymer({
            is: "my-img",
            properties: {
                "src": {
                    type: String
                }
            }
        });
    </script>
</dom-module>
```